# FastAPI Utils - repeat_every doesn't work after some time in Cloud Run

Tags: fastapi, google-cloud-run, hypercorn

I have a repeated task that runs every 15 minutes.

```
@app.on_event("startup")
@repeat_every(seconds=60 * 15, wait_first=True)
def myFunction(db=SessionLocal()) -> None:
    test(db=db, for_test=False)
```

It works pretty normal at the beginning. But after some time (Like 5-6 hours) It stops working and never repeats task again. When I check logs in Cloud Run, I see this message;

```
RuntimeError: coroutine ignored GeneratorExit
```

Also such logs;

```
2022-09-29 10:04:04.263 EETTask was destroyed but it is pending!
2022-09-29 10:04:04.263 EETtask: <Task pending name='Task-850' coro=<H2Protocol.send_task() running at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/hypercorn/protocol/h2.py:148> wait_for=<Future cancelled> cb=[_gather.<locals>._done_callback() at /usr/local/lib/python3.9/asyncio/tasks.py:767]>
```

I have to deploy a new revision to make repeated tasks work again. I'd like to know what to do in this situation and why this error occurs. It seems like there is no such problem in localhost.

Should I use Google Scheduler instead of FastApi utils' repeated tasks?

Comment: Have you tried doing this as two separate functions, instead of having the same function decorated twice? (there might be some interactions between those that hasn't been properly tested). The error can also be caused by issues inside your `test` function. Test it by wrapping two separate functions instead of wrapping one function twice.

Comment: @MatsLindh Thank you for your answer. I am pretty sure there is no error in test function. Because I'm logging every exception and trace, I could see the error. Actually I have multiple repeated tasks and this "myFunction" is just an example. 

All of them stop working after some time, not only this one.

I will try wrapping two seperate functions and test it again.

My guess "hypercorn" causes this issue but im not sure. I will run my project with uvicorn (http/1) and test again after your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was occuring because of my startup script.

I haven't noticed but i was using `--reload` tag in production. I can't believe this.

After I edited my startup script for production, everything worked fine.